# Tensorflow — Cannot call `tf.keras.Model.add_metric` when `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` is used

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I have a model class that inherits from `tf.keras.Model`. I can train, evaluate, and *export* it using 8 GPUs, distributing it with `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`. However, I need custom metrics, and when I call the [add_metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_add_metric_method) method, it throws an error when trying to **export**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repro/vae.py", line 80, in <module>
    vae.save("vae")
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1979, in save
    signatures, options)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 134, in save_model
    signatures, options)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 80, in save
    save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 976, in save
    obj, export_dir, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1047, in _build_meta_graph
    checkpoint_graph_view)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_serialization.py", line 75, in find_function_to_export
    functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 145, in list_functions
    self._serialization_cache)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2590, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    Model, self)._list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3019, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    .list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache))
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py", line 87, in list_functions_for_serialization
    fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 79, in functions_to_serialize
    serialization_cache).functions_to_serialize)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 95, in _get_serialized_attributes
    serialization_cache)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py", line 51, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    default_signature = save_impl.default_save_signature(self.obj)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 205, in default_save_signature
    fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1167, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1073, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saving_utils.py", line 134, in _wrapped_model
    outputs = model(inputs, training=False)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 985, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "repro/vae.py", line 63, in call
    self.add_metric([0.], name="foo")
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1705, in add_metric
    metric_obj(value)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 231, in __call__
    replica_local_fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py", line 1133, in call_replica_local_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 211, in replica_local_fn
    update_op = self.update_state(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 90, in decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 176, in update_state_fn
    return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py", line 373, in update_state
    update_total_op = self.total.assign_add(value_sum)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py", line 1015, in assign_add
    self, value, read_value=read_value)
  File "/Users/acarlson/anaconda3/envs/ed-autocoder-dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/values_util.py", line 95, in on_read_assign_add_cross_replica
    "SyncOnReadVariable does not support `assign_add` in "
ValueError: SyncOnReadVariable does not support `assign_add` in cross-replica context when aggregation is set to `tf.VariableAggregation.SUM`.
```

I have created a simple reproduction which shows this error here:

```
import tensorflow as tf


class Sampling(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Maps MNIST digits to a triplet (z_mean, z_log_var, z)."""

    def __init__(self, latent_dim=32, intermediate_dim=64, name="encoder", **kwargs):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.dense_proj = tf.keras.layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation="relu")
        self.dense_mean = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)
        self.dense_log_var = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim)
        self.sampling = Sampling()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_proj(inputs)
        z_mean = self.dense_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.dense_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling((z_mean, z_log_var))
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Converts z, the encoded digit vector, back into a readable digit."""

    def __init__(self, original_dim, intermediate_dim=64, name="decoder", **kwargs):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.dense_proj = tf.keras.layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation="relu")
        self.dense_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(original_dim, activation="sigmoid")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense_proj(inputs)
        return self.dense_output(x)


class VariationalAutoEncoder(tf.keras.Model):
    """Combines the encoder and decoder into an end-to-end model for training."""

    def __init__(self, original_dim, intermediate_dim=64, latent_dim=32, name="autoencoder", **kwargs):
        super(VariationalAutoEncoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.original_dim = original_dim
        self.encoder = Encoder(latent_dim=latent_dim, intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim)
        self.decoder = Decoder(original_dim, intermediate_dim=intermediate_dim)

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructed = self.decoder(z)
        # Add KL divergence regularization loss.
        kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(
            z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1
        )
        self.add_loss(kl_loss)
        self.add_metric([0.], name="foo")
        return reconstructed


(x_train, _), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

original_dim = 784

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    vae = VariationalAutoEncoder(original_dim, 64, 32)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
    vae.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

vae.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
vae.save("vae")
```

I apologize for so much code, but most of it isn't important. The important part is that this model is instantiated and compiled inside the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` scope. There is also a `self.add_metric([0.], name="foo")` in the model. If you remove that `add_metric` call, then it works. It will export correctly.

Therefore, using the `tf.keras.Model.add_metric` method with `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`. I need to be able to add my custom metrics with a distributed model.

Note: Metrics are **supposed** to be calculated in the strategy scope, as mentioned in [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy#scope)

> "Common things that create variables in TF: models, optimizers, metrics. These should always be created inside the scope."

As for versions, I'm using the Google [AI platform runtime version 2.3](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list#2.3)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in TF version 2.3, and was fixed in 2.4. I got a response on [an issue I filed with TF](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40366)